# Hide data-label="Excl. Tax" Product Page

Tags: price, tax, product-page, magento2.2.3

For my store I have

> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax -> Price Display Settings -> Display
>   Product Prices In Catalog ---> "Including and Excluding Tax"

For all products on my site the price **Excl. Tax** and price **Inc. Tax** are displayed.

[image: Price inc and excl tax]

I would like to remove the Excl. Tax data-label on the product page only. This will allow me my own label which is linked to the product attributes.

The trouble is i cannot stop the **Excl. Tax** data label from showing.

If I use CSS

```
.price-container .price-including-tax + .price-excluding-tax, .price-container .weee {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

or

```
display: none;
```

then **both** price and label are removed

[image: Price Inc Tax using display: none]

I would like to avoid having to edit core files if possible

Price Excl. Tax **template** is generated from

> /vender/magento/module-tax/view/base/templates/pricing/adjustments.phtml

```
<?php if ($block->displayBothPrices()): ?>
    <span id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->buildIdWithPrefix('price-excluding-tax-') ?>"
          data-label="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Excl. Tax')) ?>"
          data-price-amount="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getRawAmount() ?>"
          data-price-type="basePrice"
          class="price-wrapper price-excluding-tax">
        <span class="price"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayAmountExclTax() ?></span></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and **block** is

> /vender/magento/Weee/Pricing/Render/TaxAdjustment.php

Does anyone know how i can hide just the label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change label text, you can change that in translation file of tax module.

However if you want to remove tax label only on product detail page ( using css ), here is css class you have to use:

**for Product detail page :**

```
.product-info-price .price-including-tax+.price-excluding-tax:before
  { display : none }
```

**for Product and Listing page :**

```
.price-including-tax+.price-excluding-tax:before
  { display : none }
```

hope it will help